# Submit value of nicEdit text editor via ajax POST, isn't working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, nicedit

I've found a few "solutions" but nothing seems to work for me. I'm using malsup's jquery form plugin to submit form data via POST. One of the form elements is a nicEdit box. Here's my code:

html:

```
<div class="leftaligned">   
<h1>Add News:</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addnewsform" action="addnewscode.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="isnewnews" value=1 />
<div class="missinginfo">
Please add a title and some content!
</div>
<h2>Title:</h2>
<input type="text" size="50" id="newtitle" name="newtitle">
<h2>Content:</h2>
<textarea style="width:590px; height:300px;" id="newcontent" name="newcontent"></textarea>
<br>
<div id="contentbuttons">
<input type="submit" value="Add News" class="submitnews" style="float:left;" /></form>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;'/>
</div>
```

and here's what's currently called when the submit button is clicked:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = {

    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
        var title = document.getElementById("newtitle").value;
        var content = document.getElementById("newcontent").value;
        alert(content);
        var title = document.getElementById("newtitle").value;
        if(title == "" || content == "") {
            parent.$.fn.colorbox.resize({height:635});
            $(".missinginfo").show();
            setTimeout(function()     {$(".missinginfo").hide();parent.$.fn.colorbox.resize({height:610});},2000);
            return false;
        }

    },

    success:       showResponse  
}; 

$('#addnewsform').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    return false; 
});

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    parent.onAddNewsSuccess();
}  
});
</script>
```

My #newcontent text area is a nicEdit box.

The alert(content) displays nothing, so I know there's something else I need to do to get the text inside the nicEdit box to submit. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Nevermind, I solved it using:
>
> ```
>     beforeSerialize: function($form, options) {
>     nicEditors.findEditor('newcontent').saveContent();
> },
> ```